# Citation not getting displayed - instead the alias is getting displayed in the pdf

Tags: latex, tex, bibtex, biblatex

I am trying to use `\cite` to cite items from bibliography.bib. However, my citations are not working properly.

The environment, code and output are as below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,hyperref,booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable, adjustbox,apacite,dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs,longtable,lscape,placeins,tikz}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natlib,style=author-year,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\psset{unit=2cm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=red}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}

\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a \cite{sample}.

\end{document}
```

The cite takes reference from my .bib file, which is in the same folder. Here I have attached a sample citation.

```
@article{sample,
  title={What is the price elasticity of housing demand?},
  author={Hanushek, Eric A and Quigley, John M},
  journal={The Review of Economics and Statistics},
  pages={449--454},
  year={1980},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
```

The output that I am getting looks like

`Author Year` with year linking to the bibliography section. However, I want it like `Author, Year` with the entire phrase linking to the bibliography section

Could you please help me with this issue?

Thank You :)

P.S. : I know my environment is not perfect. It has some packages repeated twice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEVER IGNORE ERROR MESSAGES! After an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document. There is no point at even looking at what might or might not be valid output while there are still errors!

There are several major problems:

- don't load packages multiple times and in particular don't load them multiple times with different options. An error message in the log file will explicitly tell you about the option clash
- don't load incompatible package like apacite and biblatex in the same document. An error message in the log file with explicitly tell you that these two packages are not compatible
- the biblatex option is called `natbib`, not `natlib`. An error message will explicitly tell you that it does not know the option natlib
- the biblatex style is called `authoryear`, not `author-year`. An explicit error message will tell you that `author-year` style is not found

... and then there are many other duplicate, unnecessary or obsolete packages. You should clean up your preamble and only load the packages you need. Also hyperref should be loaded after the other packages.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,
%hyperref,
booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable, adjustbox,
%apacite,
dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs,longtable,
%lscape,
placeins,tikz}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

%\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\psset{unit=2cm}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usepackage[center]{caption}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=red}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{sample,
  title={What is the price elasticity of housing demand?},
  author={Hanushek, Eric A and Quigley, John M},
  journal={The Review of Economics and Statistics},
  pages={449--454},
  year={1980},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a \cite{sample}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.:) I was not getting any errors. I am now getting it in the correct format. However, the entire Author, Year is not getting linked and leading to references section.

Comment: @AnishaGarg You were getting errors, overleaf is just good at hiding them from their users.

Comment: Ahh okay! I changed the environment according to what you said. But still the Author, Year is not getting linked.

Comment: \bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta} is not working

Comment: @AnishaGarg That's syntax for bibtex, but you are using bib**la**tex. However if you have a new problem, ask a new question!

Comment: No, it is related to this query only. I am not able to see the bibliography, nor link it.

Comment: @AnishaGarg Your question was why the citation was not displayed - and that's what I fixed. You don't even have have a bibliography in your code.

Comment: I have written that I want Author, Year to link to the bibliography section. But I did not add the code for it. Just asked that as a question.